# Configuring a setup.py on Git for pip install

Tags: git, pip, installation

I am trying to install the [pyFM library](https://github.com/coreylynch/pyFM) from github through:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/coreylynch/pyFM
```

I ran into an error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'm.lib'
```

After reading [this answer](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/493), I deduced the best solution would be to remove 'm' in the libraries=['m'] flag currently present in the setup.py file. However, I realize that I now have a new setup.py I have to run - so I downloaded the repo and attempted to run the file in terminal, only to another error. I assume there are specific procedures included in the pip install process I am missing.

My question is, what is the best way to install this repository with my adjusted setup.py file? Perhaps there is something I could include in the terminal to ignore the library=['m'] flag? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!